# Marking route on Google map with multiple latitude and longitude values from database

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have written a PHP and javaScript code which will retrieve latitude and longitude informations from Database and place markers on Google map according in appropriate places(using lat and lon values). This works fine.

I need to join these markers and draw route on the map. How to do it.

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
   <style type="text/css">
   body { font: normal 10pt Helvetica, Arial; }
    #map { width: 350px; height: 300px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; }
    </style>
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

   var icon = new    google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
   new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
   new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
   var center = null;
   var map = null;
   var currentPopup;
   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  function addMarker(lat, lng, info)
 {
   var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
bounds.extend(pt);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
{
    position: pt,
    icon: icon,
    map: map
});
var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
{
    content: info,
    maxWidth: 300
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function()
{
    if (currentPopup != null)
    {
        currentPopup.close();
        currentPopup = null;
    }
    popup.open(map, marker);
    currentPopup = popup;
   });
    google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function()
   {
    map.panTo(center);
    currentPopup = null;
   });
   }

function initMap()
{
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
zoom: 14,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
mapTypeControl: false,
mapTypeControlOptions:
{
    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
},
navigationControl: true,
navigationControlOptions:
{
style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
 }
 });


  $.getJSON('googlescript.php', function(items)
  {
   for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      (function(item) {
        addMarker(item.lat, item.long, '<b>' + item.name + '</b><br />' + item.desc);
    })(items[i]);
   }
  });

  center = bounds.getCenter();
 map.fitBounds(bounds);

   }
   </script>
    </head>
   <body onload="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
   <div id="map"></div>
    </html>
```

Comment: Do you want to connect the markers with straight lines, or the driving route?

Comment: @duncan I just want to connect it with straight line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your JSON return function to something like this:

```
$.getJSON('googlescript.php', function(items)
  {
   var routePoints = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      (function(item) {
        addMarker(item.lat, item.long, '<b>' + item.name + '</b><br />' + item.desc);
    })(items[i]);
    routePoints.push(new google.maps.LatLng(items[i].lat,items[i].long));
   }
   var route= new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: routePoints,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  route.setMap(map);

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you look for the Polyline object and you can see how to use within the [google maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays?hl=en#Polylines)

If you got a larger project I can advice using gmap2 using .kml files. But you should be able to accomplish your goal using the google documentation easily..

Comment: I will try using polylines. Is it possible to retrieve the latitude and longitude values from database using polyline

Comment: The Javascript is working clientside so no. But you could write a PHP script creating a .kml file on the server containing your markers, markerpictures, lat&lon and all the other data you want to show e.g. in tooltips. After that you can request the kml file by your js (you will have to look for kml in google maps doc) and it will automatically display all the markers. You could also already use Polylines inside the kml. There are several other ways to do that tho but I personally found this as a good solution working with google maps especially with many markers. You could also create a json.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to learn about the [POLYLINE ARRAYS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays?hl=en#PolylineArrays) to accomplish connecting all the markers with a line. The documentation explains it very well.

However, the polyline arrays use javascript arrays, so if you are looking for fetching the `lat` `lng` values from a Database then you should look for some way to pass an array of the lat lng's fetched from database to the JavaScript function. There is already an article in the site that shows how to work [Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3) . Look into the article and learn using polyline arrays and that should help you out.